# possible to use session_start() inside included file?

Tags: php, session, header

I have 2 pages one is index.php other is classes.php

should not this work classes.php:

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
  include "classes.php";
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  echo "Loaded";
?>
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /public_html/index.php:1) in /public_html/includes/classes.php on line 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you do not send **anything** before anything regarding session is executed.

That means:

- remove **everything** before `<?php`,
- remove trailing `?>` tags (they are not required and often harmful),

The problem you experienced is caused by something that is before "`<?php`" within `index.php` file (it may be a space, tab, end of line or anything else you did not show us), but if you follow the above rules, you should have this issue a lot less often during further development of your application.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure there is no white space before the opening `<?php` tag in your classes and index files.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an include issue - you have whitespace somewhere, possibly in classes.php after the `?>`.

Answer (score 1):

`output started at /public_html/index.php:1`

Apparently you have white-space (or possibly content) before the PHP start tag in your index.php file which is being sent as output.

Answer (score 0):

check your php.ini and see if you have the `session.auto_start` set to 1(or true, or yes).

If you want to start the session manually, it should be set to 0

More info here:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

if it is already set to 0, then you have a space or a new line at the beginning of index.php, try to make sure that you do not see any weird char